# Dynamic configuration of Azure B2C with user flows in a .NET 6 API

Tags: c#, azure

I have a .NET 6 API with authorization via a B2C tenant. This B2C tenant has two user flows:

1. B2C_1_CustomerSignUpAndSignIn
2. B2C_1_EmployeeSignUpAndSignIn

We also have a manager application which has to connect to the same API, which makes 3 schemes in total.

In my API I have configured the following in the `Program.cs`

```
builder
    .Services
    .AddAuthentication()
    .AddScheme<JwtBearerOptions, CustomJwtHandler>("AzureB2cApplicationBased", options => builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureB2cApplicationBasedJwtBearerOptions", options))
    .AddScheme<JwtBearerOptions, CustomJwtHandler>("AzureB2cCustomerSignUpAndSignIn", options => builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureB2cCustomerSignUpAndSignInJwtBearerOptions", options))
    .AddScheme<JwtBearerOptions, CustomJwtHandler>("AzureB2cEmployeeSignUpAndSignIn", options => builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureB2cEmployeeSignUpAndSignInJwtBearerOptions", options))
    .Services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IPostConfigureOptions<JwtBearerOptions>, JwtBearerPostConfigureOptions>()); // Without this JwtBearerOptions.ConfigurationManager is null.
builder
    .Services
    .AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .AddAuthenticationSchemes("AzureB2cApplicationBased", "AzureB2cCustomerSignUpAndSignIn", "AzureB2cEmployeeSignUpAndSignIn")
            .Build();
        options.AddPolicy(
            "Employee",
            policy =>
            {
                // All authentication schemes must be added, otherwise an empty ClaimsPrincipal is given to the API methods.
                policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes("AzureB2cApplicationBased", "AzureB2cCustomerSignUpAndSignIn", "AzureB2cEmployeeSignUpAndSignIn");
                policy.Requirements.Add(new RoleRequirement("Employee"));
            });
        options.AddPolicy(
            "RegisteredUser",
            policy =>
            {
                // All authentication schemes must be added, otherwise an empty ClaimsPrincipal is given to the API methods.
                policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes("AzureB2cApplicationBased", "AzureB2cCustomerSignUpAndSignIn", "AzureB2cEmployeeSignUpAndSignIn");
                policy.Requirements.Add(new RoleRequirement("RegisteredUser"));
            });
        options.AddPolicy(
            "VerifiedCustomer",
            policy =>
            {
                // All authentication schemes must be added, otherwise an empty ClaimsPrincipal is given to the API methods.
                policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes("AzureB2cApplicationBased", "AzureB2cCustomerSignUpAndSignIn", "AzureB2cEmployeeSignUpAndSignIn");
                policy.Requirements.Add(new RoleRequirement("VerifiedCustomer"));
            });
        options.AddPolicy(
            "CustomerOrVerifiedCustomer",
            policy =>
            {
                // All authentication schemes must be added, otherwise an empty ClaimsPrincipal is given to the API methods.
                policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes("AzureB2cApplicationBased", "AzureB2cCustomerSignUpAndSignIn", "AzureB2cEmployeeSignUpAndSignIn");
                policy.Requirements.Add(new RoleRequirement("CustomerOrVerifiedCustomer"));
            });
    });
```

This code has been here for ages, it works, but I've never been happy with it.

1. I'm using a custom `JwtBearerHandler` called `CustomJwtHandler` which makes sure a token is only verified against the user flow it was created for. If I didn't then the code tried to authenticate against all the user flows, which slows down the authenticated requests by a great deal when you have a lot of user flows. We used to have more, so the difference is less present now, but still noticable. Is there a better way?
2. Currently if I add or remove a user flow, I have to manually update the `Program.cs` to remove or add this user flow to the `AddAuthentication` and `AddAuthorization` methods. If deletion is forgotten, then the authorized endpoints throw an error after the API is reloaded (read: after the scheme metadata cache is cleared), which is what happened today on development. Therefore, I would prefer this to be dynamic. I tried calling the Graph API (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/identitycontainer-list-b2cuserflows?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=powershell) using the client credentials flow after granting the API `IdentityUserFlow.Read.All`, `IdentityUserFlow.ReadWrite.All` rights to build this dynamically, but calling this Graph API endpoint doesn't seem to work as I can only use the default scope (note: calling other endpoints does work). Is there a better way?
3. I don't like that the authorization metadata cache is only loaded the first time anyone is making an authorized request. I want to preload this. Can this be done?
4. I noticed that, since upgrading to .NET 6, when I remove the code adding all the authentication schemes to the different policies, I still retrieve a ClaimsPrincipal, so I'm assuming something changed here and it is no longer necessary.